# Can adding an additional feature to a perceptron classifier make the results worse?

Tags: classification, feature-selection, naive-bayes, perceptron

I am using perceptron to solve a classification problem.
I have a limited amount of features (26) and iterate through all possible combinations of them.
A combination of two features [feature_a, feature_b] results in better accuracy than the same combination with additional third feature [feature_a, feature_b, feature_c].
Is there any reasonable explanation for that apart from a bug in my code?

I tried replacing perceptron by naive bayes classifiers, the pattern persists.

I am using scikit-learn Python library for perceptron and NB implementations, if that's important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that is the problem of overfitting. Adding features can always improve training acc. in such a shallow model, but may hurt generalization.

p.s., I think you may try logsitic regression or linear SVM rather than perception.

Comment: I thought overfitting would occur if I had much more features than 3, is it possible with such a simple model?

Comment: Suppose you add a third random feature, which is not discriminative at all. That will only make things worse. Also I think another possibility is due to the perception learning algorithm, which cares only about correctly or not classifying the training data, without any measure of degree or probability.

Comment: Note that in nonlinear models (especially, say, RBF-SVMs), adding features can have much more direct negative influences. But yeah, there's really no reason to be using perceptrons rather than logistic regression / linear SVM; it's just a bad optimization algorithm for a very similar problem.